# Unknown format of HTML nested in JSON response

Tags: html, xml, templates, xpath

I'm trying to scrape a website which has its HTML nested in a JSON response. I can't use XPath on the nested HTML because it's in a weird templated format, is there any way of converting this to regular XML?

The first part of the nested xml looks like this:

```
{"template":"
<html>\n 
    <head><\/head>\n 
        <body>\n  
            <h3 class=\"hide\">Goods list<\/h3> \n  
                <!-- type_list --> \n  
                <div class=\"total_listing_wrap\"> \n   
                    <ul class=\"tt_listbox sell_sec\"> \n    
                        <li id=\"thisClick_1730512587\" data-ctgrrank=\"0\" data-seq=\"1\"> \n     
                            <div class=\"total_listitem\"> \n      
                                <div class=\"photo_wrap\" name=\"prdPhoto\"> \n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a JSON parser to extract the HTML as text, followed by an HTML parser to convert the HTML to a node tree.

With XPath 3.1 you can do it all in a single step, e.g.:

```
let $doc := parse-xml(json-doc('input.json')?template)
return $doc//div[@class='total_listitem']
```

(That's assuming the HTML is well-formed XML...)

Comment: Thanks for your response, is this with Python? Did you use a library other than XPath?

Comment: XPath 3.1 is available to Python users via the Saxon/C product. (But of course, that's a significant piece of technology to take on board, so it all depends how big a project this is.)

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. I'm actually using a data analytics platform called KNIME which has a built in XPath node, which uses XPath 2.0. Thanks though